# Does $(0, \infty)$ inherit its usual topology as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_K$?

Tags: general-topology

Recall that $\mathbb{R}_K$ denotes the real line with the $K$ topology. In other words, its basis elements are of the form $(a, b) - K$, where $K = \{1/n: n \in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$. On page 178 of Munkres's 'Topology' book, the author states that $(0, \infty)$ inherits its usual topology as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_K$. But I disagree because $(0,1) - K$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_K$ and so its intersection with $(0,\infty)$ is open in $(0, \infty)$. In other words, $((0,1) - K) \cap (0, \infty) = (0,1) - K$ is open in $(0, \infty)$, but the standard topology on $(0, \infty)$ does NOT have $(0,1) - K$ as one of its open sets. So where am I wrong in my argument here? I am assuming that Munkres is correct and I am not. Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, This is part of the argument that $\Bbb R_K$ is connected: $(0,+\infty)$ is connected and $(-\infty,0]$ is too (also has same subspace topology as Euclidean) and these are non-separated in $\Bbb R_K$ so their union is connected too. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3704875/4280).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, $(0,1)\setminus K$ **is** open in the standard topology: it is equal to the intersection of the open sets $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\big(\{0\}\cup K\big)$. The latter is open because $\{0\}\cup K$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

$K$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology, but it **is** closed in $(0,+\infty)$ in its subspace topology (as $K = (K \cup \{0\}) \cap (0, +\infty)$, so the intersection of a closed subset of $\Bbb R$ with the subspace). So the $K$-topology adds no new sets to the subspace topology on $(0,+\infty)$, hence Munkres' remark.